# Ajax call leads to page reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have the following AJAX call in a React method:

```
  handleActivitySubmit: function handleActivitySubmit(activity, urlActivity, callbackMy) {
    console.log("making query with activity: " + JSON.stringify(activity));
    $.ajax({
      url: urlActivity,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      data: activity,
      success: function (data) {
        callbackMy(Object.keys(data));
      }.bind(this),
      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(urlActivity, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

Whenever the call is unsuccessful, the entire page reloads and all the state is lost.

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML form must be submitting the form to `action = url`. This is the default way in which forms are handled, i.e. if you click element `<input type="submit" .. />` it will always reload the browser.  You will need to use `event.preventDefault()` within your handler to prevent the default action.

Get the click event on form submit as the last argument of `handleActivitySubmit` i.e.

```
handleActivitySubmit: function handleActivitySubmit(activity, urlActivity, callbackMy, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // your remaining code
  }
```